# how to test a string contained in a variable with a readlink output?

Tags: bash, unix

A user enters a file name --> $1. i compare that with path2. If both strings match, it echoes "Same file". I have included the code below.

```
path="$(readlink -f $1)"
path2="path/to/$USER/file"

if [[ $path == $path2 ]] ; then
    echo "Same file"
```

However, when i run this with the input file same as path2, it still shows a mismatch as it is comparing **path/to/username/file** with **path/to/username\file**. How do i get the path2 to output in the same format as path? i.e. path2 should output as **path/to/username/file** instead of **path/to/username\file**

Thank you!

Comment: The quotes are removed when parsing the assignment, it's not comparing them literally. The problem is something else.

Comment: You're missing the `$` before the variables: `if [[ $path == $path2 ]]`

Comment: There is no single quote in path2 in your example

Comment: oops sorry, i did include the $path == $path2 in my code, i realised since my path2 is path2= 'file/to/$USER/path', it is comparing 'file/to/username\path with 'file/to/username/path'

Comment: Where is that backslash coming from? Those normally only show up in paths on Windows, not on unix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-ef` that also works with ksh93, zsh, bash… rather than `readlink` that is GNU coreutils specific :

```sh
if [ "$1" -ef "path/to/$USER/file" ] ; then
    echo "Same file"
```

`help test`

> `FILE1 -ef FILE2`  True if `file1` is a hard link to `file2`.